# Resizing the bounding box of when a line is rotated

Tags: javascript

I would like a bit of help on something I am currently working on.  I am trying to rotate a line object with a bounding box.  I can rotate the line no problem, however I am unable to get the bounding box to readjust itself to the rotated line.

Hopefully this image can help. 
[image: Starting Image]

The line currently rotates from the top left corner. It starts off at 45 degress.  When I rotate it to say 90, I get the following result:

[image]

Is there a formula I can use to resize the bounding box so that the line length is within the bounds of the bounding box.  I am not very stellar at maths and have been brushing up on sin, cosine etc, but still unable to come up with a decent solution.

Any help with this would be appreciated.  Thank you,

Samuel

Comment: If you can access CSS property for the boundary element then set the boundary element's overflow: hidden.

Comment: Just to clarify: how do you rotate the line? how do you calculate the bounding box? After rotation you can just recalculate the bbox? Or do you actually need to rotate the bounding box as well? Are you using a library to represent lines and bounding boxes, or are you drawing lines/bounding boxes on a canvas or using svg?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the CSS based solution to your problem. You can set ***overflow:hidden*** to hide the overflow line

```css
.boundary {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden; //Key to hide the line which overflows the container
}

.boundary:hover .line {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.line {
  width: 1px;
  height: 200%;
  background-color: blue;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: rotate(315deg);
  transition: transform 1.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="boundary">
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```